# Coeffcient of variation(CV) with time

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I am using an equation that predicts chloride content in concrete at a certain time. All my parameters are random variables. The problem is that as time increases my mean increases and standard deviation with the same ratio. which make my Cv constant with time.

so how can I show that as time passes uncertainty increases which feels right but that Cv doesn't show that and remains constant

Comment: You discovered heteroskedasticity. (+1)

Comment: An SD proportional to the mean is a clear signal that you should be analyzing the logarithms of the concentrations rather than the concentrations themselves.  As you likely know, there are good chemical reasons to be expressing low-level proportions of mixtures in terms of their logarithms, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on what you mean by "uncertainty". One reasonable definition is the CV, but that's constant in your case. Another possibility is the standard deviation - in your data, that increases with time, so you could show that.

Graphically, you could make a scatterplot of time and chloride content and draw lines (possibly confidence intervals, possibly something else) showing how the variation changes over time.